# IDictionary vs Hashtable -

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Lots of sources talks about this question but I dont understand the concept very well. IDictionary is generic, its type safety etc.

When I dig into EntityFrameworkv5 I see a property that is declared as below in the LogEntry class.

```
private IDictionary<string, object> extendedProperties;
```

The question is why they prefer IDictionary against Hashtable, hence Hashtable is also takes a key as a string and a object. Only the reason is making the property polymorphic by choosing IDictionary ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to use a non-generic `HashTable` over a generic `IDictionary`? At least with the generic dictionary, the keys can be constrained to `strings`.  With the non-generic hash table, the keys can be any object and that may not be desirable. Non-generic collections are only around due to legacy issues, using generic collections, you can do much more with.

Comment: Or maybe they were tired of having to issue `Cast<KeyValuePair<string, object>>()` to be able to use LINQ with that collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, there are few reasons to use `Hashtable`. `Dictionary<>` is better than it in most respects. When it's not, you can usually find another strongly typed collection that serves your purpose even better than either.

- Type-safe.
- None of the severe overhead of boxing and unboxing.
- Implements `IDictionary<>`, which is very compatible with .NET and 3rd party code.
- Performs better than `Hashtable` in many areas. See links:  [Link #1](http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable), [Link #2](http://www.technolatte.net/2011/07/dictionary-and-hashtable-benchmarking.html).

If you're asking why type a property as `IDictionary<>` instead of `Dictionary<>`, it's for several reasons.

- It is generally considered best practice to use interfaces as often as possible, instead of regular types, especially in a framework.
- It is possible to change the implementation of the interface fairly easily, but it's difficult to change the nature of a concrete class without causing compatibility problems with dependent code.
- Using interfaces, you can take advantage of [Covariance and Contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.asp).
- External code is more likely to consume the more general interface `IDictionary<>` than the concrete class `Dictionary<>`. Using `IDictionary<>` thus lets other developers to interact better with the property.
- There are tons more, probably. These are just off the top of my head.

Comment: Check the links. One of them has a plot. Short answer: `Hashtable` sucks.

Comment: Actually, `Hashtable` searches faster than `IDictionary`. Plus, `Hashtable` is thread-safe. `IDictionary` is not. Therefore, `Hashtable` still has uses, especially when applications need to scale up for performance reasons. Sorry, `IDictionary` is *not* the magic bullet.

Comment: Oh. You're right. I misremembered. It does look up items faster than a generic dictionary. Not that much faster, but it is certainly there. Though I would like to point out that `IDictionary<>` has nothing to do with thread safety; it's just an interface. There is an implementation, `ConcurrentDictionary<>`, which *is* thread safe. And, unlike `Hashtable`, the thread safety of which is limited, it's really thread safe.

Comment: Faster than IDictionary? Huh?

Comment: IDictionary itself has no scaling or thread capability. You would need to know the implementation that the framework actually used behind the interface (probably just Dictionary<>) to actually make any analysis of what was going on. Theoretically you could wrap a Hashtable with an IDictionary facade/adapter

Comment: @GregRos: umm... I would agree that `Hashtable` thread model does look peculiar, if you were looking into the code via Reflector. Not sure about the claim that thread safety is *limited* though. The difference between the `ConcurrentDictionary`'s use of the `Monitor.Enter/Exit` and `Hashtable`'s `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion` is that the `Hashtable` is implementing virtualized thread locks in order to avoid using expensive threading resources (which `Monitor` had a history of using, btw). Other than that, both thread models work about the same in terms of effectiveness, IMHO.

Comment: Ah, I got that from the documentation. I didn't go as far as look at the IL. Compare [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx)'s thread safety section with [ConcurrentDictionary<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)'s. I doubt I would ever use Hashtable for threading purposes, had I any choice in the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes if they had defined extendedproperies as returning hashtable then they would have been stuck with that for all time, unless they wanted to break all the code that uses extended properties.

Whole point of the returning an Interface is it doesn't matter how the method is implemented as long as it keeps doing that.

"Only reason is making the property polymorphic" misses the point, there should be very few reasons why you shouldn't do this. If you can return an interface do return an interface, most of the time that's good design.

Answer (score 1):

So most of the answers here are about comparing Dictionary to Hashtable for general purposes, not why they chose that particular implementation.

In that particular implementation, you are correct, it is using object as the return type, so the strongly typed benefits of dictionary are not available.

IMO it boils down to New vs Old, ArrayList, Hashtable etc are the older tech, and are largely disfavored in general, because they do not have a host of features (described in the other answers). Although those features are not used in this particular case, there are no strong benefits for switching back to the old tech, and it provides a better example for personal development.

So its more just  a matter of "this is the way we do it now"

Answer (score 0):

The HashTable is weakly typed and can only return Object. The Dictionary<> is strongly typed for whatever type you are storing in it.